# Are there contexts where you would use the phrase "time frame" rather than the word "window" when talking about an interval of time?

Tags: word-usage, difference

Can you please tell me if there are there contexts where you would use the phrase *time frame* rather than the word *window* when talking about an interval of time? For example, do both sound perfectly natural and mean the same thing in the context below?

> Kate will arrive within a three-hour **time frame**.
>
> Kate will arrive within a three-hour **window**.

Comment: I would never say "time frame."

Comment: *Time frame* has become popular since the 1960's -- see https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time+frame&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: time frame and window [of time] do not mean the same thing at all.

Comment: I think both of these uses are OK and mean the same thing.   Personally, I use "window" for this, when I am talking about a range with a start and an end during which an event will happen. but I don't know exactly when.

Answer (score 0):

*Time frame* has become fairly [popular since the 1960's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time%20frame&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

If you [look over a greater *time frame*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time%20frame&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), there have been some uses in the 16th and 17th century.

Answer (score -2):

Generally, if you refer to a "window" in this context, you may be talking about an unspecified time period. This is not a universal condition, but it's common. One might talk about a "launch window" for a missile, in which case there is a definite period being duscussed. On the other hand, you might talk about a "window of opportunity" in very general terms.

The term "time frame" always refers to a specified time period.

Comment: I think it’s more common for a window to have a start and end. For example, when I order groceries online, I choose a 2 hour “delivery window” during which the groceries should arrive.

Comment: Yes, a window has a definite start and an end - even if these are unknown.   A "frame" does not, necessarily - for example when speaking about time sense in language here on ELL, I often talk about "time frame".